# Is it possible to have a "wrap" behaviour in QMenu?

Tags: qt, qmenu

I have to store many items in a `QMenu`. If there is too many items `QMenu` wraps them ans begins a new column, but it happens only if these items can not fit into screen height.

I'd like to have `QMenu` which wraps items when the menu height reaches, for example, parent widget's height or any other custom value.

I wasn't able to find any properties in `QMenu` for achieving this. Setting `maximumHeight` gave no result. After digging into `QMenu` sources I found that the "wrapping logic" works based on `popupGeometry` method result. But `popupGeometry` uses screen size, and it is private so I don't know a way to change it.

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't find the answer, I had to implement this control by myself.
It is a popup widget, using `QToolButton` as an owner. It can arrange items in a grid depending on item's height and required menu height.

```
class myLabel:public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    // QObject interface
public:
    myLabel(QWidget* parent=0):QLabel(parent){}
    bool event(QEvent *e)
    {
        if(e->type()==QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
            emit clicked();
        return QLabel::event(e);
    }
    void setAction(QAction *a)
    {
        setText(a->text());
        _action=a;
    }
    QAction* action()
    {
        return _action;
    }
signals:
    void clicked();
private:
    QAction* _action;
};

class myMenu: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myMenu(QWidget* owner,QWidget* parent=0):QWidget(parent){
        this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup);
        l = new QGridLayout(this);
        l->setContentsMargins(QMargins(3,3,3,3));
        _owner=owner;
        QString style="QLabel:hover{background-color: white;} ";
        setStyleSheet(style);
    }
    void addAction(QAction*a){_actions.append(a);}
    QVector<QAction*> actions(){return _actions;}
    void setItemHeight(int val){_itemHeight=val;}
    void setHeight(int val){_height=val;}
private:
    QVector<QAction*> _actions;
    QGridLayout *l ;
    QWidget*_owner;
    int _itemHeight=30;
    int _height=200;
private slots:
    void popup()
    {
        clear();
        //move popup under toolbutton
        QPoint p = _owner->geometry().bottomLeft();
        p.setY(p.y()+1);
        this->move(_owner->parentWidget()->mapToGlobal(p));
        //calculate rows count
        int rows = _height/_itemHeight;
        //calculate cols count
        int cols = _actions.size()/rows;
        int d = _actions.size()%rows;
        if(d>0)
            cols++;
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            {
                int index = i+j*rows;
                if(index<_actions.size())
                {
                    myLabel *lb = new myLabel(this);
                    connect(lb,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(onClick()));
                    lb->setFixedHeight(_itemHeight);
                    lb->setAction(_actions[index]);
                    l->addWidget(lb,i,j);
                }
            }
        this->repaint();
        this->show();
    }
    void clear()
    {
        while(l->itemAt(0)!=NULL)
        {
            QLayoutItem* i = l->takeAt(0);
            if(i->widget())
                delete i->widget();
            if(i->layout())
                delete i->layout();
            delete i;
        }
    }
    void onClick()
    {
        myLabel *g = qobject_cast<myLabel*>(sender());
        g->action()->trigger();
        close();
    }
    // QWidget interface
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)
    {
        qobject_cast<QToolButton*>(_owner)->setDown(false);
    }
signals:
    void closed();
};
```

There's also an example showing how to create and fill `myMenu` and how to receive a selected action.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
  //set-up myMenu, btMyMenu is a QToolButton
    myMenu *mMenu = new myMenu(ui->btMyMenu,this);
    connect(ui->btMyMenu,SIGNAL(pressed()),mMenu,SLOT(popup()));
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        QAction *a = new QAction("Action "+QString::number(i),this);
        connect(a,SIGNAL(triggered(bool)),this,SLOT(onActSelected()));
        mMenu->addAction(a);
    }
    //mMenu can be customized
    mMenu->setHeight(100);
    mMenu->setItemHeight(50);
}

void MainWindow::onActSelected()
{
    QAction *a = qobject_cast<QAction*>(sender());
    ui->btMyMenu->setText(a->text());
}
```

Any comments about how to improve this solution are appreciated!

Comment: was there a reason not to derive from QMenu and specialize it?

Comment: @Hayt Um.. Well I don't know how subclassing QMenu can help me with that... Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Not really I just would have thought that you use the already existing functions of QMenu instead of reimplementing it yourself. And the function for the amount of columns or size hints are protected in the QMenu to they could be overriden. I just thought you tried that and decided against it. Did not know you did not even think about it.

Comment: @Hayt no, I thought, that was my first thought, it just didn't popped in my mind that I may override protected functions (and honestly I didn't notice the one about column amount), thank you, I'll take a look!